# JavaScript Intellisense in VS2010 extremely slow and memory hungry

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, memory, intellisense, performance

I'm having 2 problems with the Intellisense in VS2010. Our project is very large, it consists of a couple hundred .js files comprising a couple hundred thousand lines of code. After using VS2010 for as little as 5-10 minutes the memory usage can easily climb to over 1gb, which causes a significant slow down, and every time I CTRL+TAB between files "Updating JavaScript Intellisense" appears in the status bar. All of our .js files have  tags so Intellisense knows where to find related code, each .js can easily reference 20-30 other .js files.

So I'm assuming every time you CTRL+TAB or open a new .js file the Intellisense gets rebuilt, and to me it looks like it rebuilds Intellisense every time you CTRL+TAB regardless of whether you made any changes or now, and it never appears to release any memory, the memory usage never goes down.

I've tried every solution I've found online, even some that seemed stupid because I'm getting desperate, I even installed VS2010 SP1 Beta today hoping Microsoft had fixed it - no.

Closing TABS doesn't help either, the memory usage remains high.
My current solution is to restart VS2010 every 30-60 minutes and try keep a minimum number of files open.

Any ideas?

Comment: VS2010 a memory hog? No way! (Sorry, had to). VS2010 seems to use around 1GB no matter what I'm doing in my current project. Perhaps you need more ram on your development workstations if that's slowing it down and there are no current fixes (I know, crappy response).

Comment: My PC has 6gb of RAM :-/, I probably should have said, when its using 1gb for a .NET project it isn't as slow as 1gb for a JavaScript project. And when its using say 400-500mb for the JavaScript project it is also fine. its only when it starts hitting 1gb or so that it slows down like crazy. Tabbing is slow, sometimes clicking on the IDE is unresponsive and you can only use the keyboard. Additionally, we use /// <reference /> tags a lot.

Comment: I've experience the same problem. Just try a different IDE. I'm a dotnet developer but do all my ajax and web dev in webstorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/. The javascript code completion is incredible! Give it a try.

Comment: My fix in the linked item here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598579/why-does-visual-studio-2010-slow-down-when-editing-a-large-js-file

Answer (score 1):

Although I've faced same issue, this situation has not been after resolving circular reference and typo of comment for JS intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have re-sharper installed in VS ?? Uninstalling re-sharper may help you to get ride of this.