# Why does Visual Studio 2010 slow down when editing a large .js file?

Tags: javascript, performance, visual-studio-2010

I have .js file that is currently over 4400 lines, editing it is very slow (about a second delay from keypress to character appearing in the document).

Are there any particular performance issues related to editing large file or JavaScript files?

N.B. I am using VS2010 SP1 and am running it with 16GB of RAM, and have installed http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626570/javascript-intellisense-in-vs2010-extremely-slow-and-memory-hungry Seems to be a intellisense memory issue, however I couldn't find a fix online. Good luck.

Comment: No, but I am using: DXCore, CodeRush, CodeRuleXpress, Refactor! for ASP.NET and Refactor! Pro (all version 10.2.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the JSOutlining extension has improved this.

Comment: I had the same issues, and turning off all my JS extensions drastically improved my usability.

Comment: Spoke too soon, found another file in my project (coffee-script.js v 1.2.0) that is killing my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I found a solution to my 10 second or more editor delay.  Disclaimer: I'm using a Dell Latitude Quad i5-2450M CPU @ 2.5GHz with 8G RAM on Win 7 Enterprise.

And now, the fix:  I changed my power settings to the highest performance plan (in my case, Ultra).  This resulted in performance increases across the board for VS 2010, not just in the text editor.  I'm a bit ashamed that it was so easy after uninstalling, reninstalling, un-extensioning, etc.   Note: This *will* kill your battery if you're not plugged in.  Hope this helps!